# Mendeley not keeping citation key when importing .bib file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, mendeley

I would like to use Mendeley to manage my references and have been writing my paper in Overleaf.

I am trying to import a .bib file into Mendeley and have found that when importing the .bib file, all the citation keys are stripped from the .bib.

This is not ideal since I am migrating across from another reference management software and have already cited several pages of writing using the citation keys from the .bib file.

How can I import my .bib file into Mendeley in a way that retains the citation keys?

I have tried importing into "Mendeley Desktop", "Mendeley Reference Manager" and Mendeley library online.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT - .BIB FILES BEFORE AND AFTER IMPORT TO MENDELEY**

Before Import

```
    @Article{YangNon-StationaryScenarios,
  author    = {Yang, Mi and Ai, Bo and He, Ruisi and Ma, Zhangfeng and Zhong, Zhangdui and Wang, Junhong and Pei, Li and Li, Yujian and Li, Jing and Wang, Ning},
  journal   = {IEEE Transactions on Vehicular Technology},
  title     = {{Non-Stationary Vehicular Channel Characterization in Complicated Scenarios}},
  year      = {2021},
  number    = {9},
  pages     = {8387--8400},
  volume    = {70},
  publisher = {IEEE},
}

@article{Zhai2021MultifrequencyTunnels,
    title = {{Multifrequency Channel Characterization for Curved Tunnels}},
    year = {2021},
    journal = {IEEE Antennas and Wireless Propagation Letters},
    author = {Zhai, Menglin and Zhai, Kai and Cui, Hengrong and Li, Demin},
    number = {12},
    month = {12},
    pages = {2457--2460},
    volume = {20},
    publisher = {Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers Inc.},
    doi = {10.1109/LAWP.2021.3114553},
    issn = {15485757},
    keywords = {Channel analysis, curved tunnel, millimeter wave, ray tracing, vehicle-to-vehicle (V2V)}
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

After Import

```
@article{Zhai2021,
abstract = {In this letter, the channel characteristics of tunnels with different curvatures at different frequencies for vehicle-to-vehicle communications are investigated. The relationship between the mean value of path loss, delay spread (DS), frequency, and curvature is analyzed. A high-order polynomial is proposed to describe the path loss exponent (PLE) and a first-order polynomial is used to fit the root-mean-square (RMS) DS. Finally, the neural network is used to build a model to predict the PLE and RMS-DS and to verify the proposed model.},
author = {Zhai, Menglin and Zhai, Kai and Cui, Hengrong and Li, Demin},
doi = {10.1109/LAWP.2021.3114553},
issn = {15485757},
journal = {IEEE Antennas and Wireless Propagation Letters},
keywords = {Channel analysis,curved tunnel,millimeter wave,ray tracing,vehicle-to-vehicle (V2V)},
month = {dec},
number = {12},
pages = {2457--2460},
publisher = {Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers Inc.},
title = {{Multifrequency Channel Characterization for Curved Tunnels}},
volume = {20},
year = {2021}
}
@article{Yang,
author = {Yang, M and Ai, B and He, R and Ma, Z and {\ldots}, Z Zhong - IEEE Transactions and undefined 2021},
journal = {ieeexplore.ieee.org},
title = {{Non-Stationary Vehicular Channel Characterization in Complicated Scenarios}},
url = {https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9485046/?casa_token=b3G0fMj0mBAAAAAA:ir0N2wkaAZMwoLFT05STYQbF4JPUCSVscdAwmdu3As2gyk2EisWJ4p8UEIkBaYukVo3QRJVLl34}
}
```

As you can see, the citation keys have been changed by Mendeley

Comment: You probably need to show some code here. Can you share a `.bib` file before importing into Mendelay and after exporting from `Mendeley` ? At least then we have an idea what we are working with.

Comment: Hi @daleif code has been attached!

Comment: You probably need to talk to Mendeley support (if they have such a thing). It seems to be doing a lot of things wrong: The `author` on `Yang` also seems wrong, whereas the original is correctly formatted. I don't use Mendeley so cannot help further. But I agree that this looks very suspicious.

Comment: Yess - it looks like Mendeley is looking the .bib files in a database and taking the new bibtex references from that database rather than the imported .bib that I want it tube doing - Mendeley seems to be adding the URL too!

I wonder if this is something we're stuck with or if it is configurable - sometimes Mendeley can be a bit rigid!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I managed to partly solve it by transforming the .bib into .XML and only then importing it into Mendeley.
Keep in mind that the result is a bit of a mess, but at least all the citations are there.